# Efficient way to overwrite many to many records in EF Core

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have many to many relationship defined as follows between user and roles. I have an API that accepts list of role_ids to replace roles of a given user. If a user has a role that is not in this new list it will be removed, otherwise kept/added. What is the efficient way to go about this without having to use multiple foreach statements and lots of queries in Entity Framework Core?

```
    public class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Role
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IList<User> Users { get; set; }

    }

    public class UserRole
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Actually there is one query, two `foreach` and one `SaveChanges`.

Comment: Haha .. I ended up writing that. Im new to efcore, so I thought maybe there is a better solution. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Only via third party extensions which can send `MERGE` statement. Then it will just one database roundtrip.